# Kendo knockout dropdownlist change Event not firing

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-mvc, knockout-kendo

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data:$root.brands,
                                       value: BrandID,
                                       dataTextField: 'Name',
                                       dataValueField: 'BrandID'},
                 event: { change: $root.saveItem }" />
```

Does anyone know why wouldn't the change event fire if this is inside a kendo window??

I am using knockout-kendo.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Change Event Firing

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList:{ data            :$root.brands,
                                      value           :BrandID,
                                      dataTextField   :'Name',
                                      dataValueField  :'BrandID',
                                      change          :$root.saveItem}"/>
```

[Here is sample of change event firing](http://jsfiddle.net/AcJRC/)